# What does the DevTools message "Styles Invalidated" mean?

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, google-chrome-devtools

This message is the explanation given for a "Recalculate Style" record in *Developer Tools -> Timeline -> Frames*.  The only search results I can find for this string are references to its location in the Webkit localization source.

I have an otherwise perfectly smooth set of 60fps animations running, except for this occasional "Styles invalidated" hiccup that consumes 100+ms once in a while.  Said hiccups show up in one of two places, as indicated in the hover state for the DevTools timeline graph:

1) A greensock Timeline that is having its playhead moved back and forth to control the animation of an element being `translateX`'d across the screen.

2) A block of code that directly sets the transform on a small set of rotating elements:

```
while(i--) {
    gears[i].style['WebkitTransform'] = 'rotate3d(0,0,1,' + (delta * rotations[i]) + 'deg)';
}
```

[image: screencap of devtools timeline]

Both of these are called from within a `requestAnimationFrame` loop, and the only properties being modified anywhere in the code are the transforms `rotate`/`rotate3d` and `translate`/`translateX`/`translate3d` (I've tried them with and without 3d).

I've also tried disabling one or the other of `translateX` and `rotate`, but they each individually still seem to cause the issue.

Comment: Do you have a reduced test case?
Are there other Recalculate Style events that were forced by the same line of code and took much less time.
What values for rotate3d were used in the both cases, long and short.

Comment: @wonderfool, did you ever figure this out?